# How to solve jsPDF integration issue with VITE

Tags: vite, jspdf

While migrating to VITE from create-react-app, jsPDF is breaking.

jsPDF is using require function to load other modules internally, and VITE is not supporting '**require**' function. So, while calling jsPDF, page is breaking with '**require**' is not a function error.

jsPDF library should work with VITE.